# How to split a table into Master/Detail, with generating id SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I stored a flat file into a table.

The tag P is for the master
The tag I is for the detail

Always a P row was precede with a (n) numbers of  I rows.

The problem is, The I rows doesn't have an ID to join the P row.

Need to generate an ID to join the P row with the I rows.

The P row have a two fields that can be helpful.
The field "SequenceNumber" store the sequential ID.
The field "NumberOfItems" store how many I rows belong to a P Row.

I Need to split the data in two tables master/detail with identifiying ID.
I attach an image with the data

Thanks So Much

```
Original Table
RecordType SequenceNumber NumberOfItems TicketHeaderKey UnitID
P          1              3             ;               1
I          19900          0             FA              19900
I          3000           0             BK              3000
I          0              0             BK              0
P          2              1             ;               1
I          19900          0             FA              19900
P          3              2             ;               1
I          19900          0             FA              19900
I          3000           0             BK              3000

Need Split into two tables some like this

Master Table
RecordType SequenceNumber NumberOfItems TicketHeaderKey UnitID
P          1              3             ;               1
P          2              1             ;               1
P          3              2             ;               1

Detail Table
RecordType SequenceNumber idMasterTable TicketHeaderKey UnitID
I          19900          1             FA              19900
I          3000           1             BK              3000
I          0              1             BK              0
I          19900          2             FA              19900
I          19900          3             FA              19900
I          3000           3             BK              3000
```

[SQL TABLE TO SPLIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THyfB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My primary concern is that you do not have a proper row sequence in the original table.  Without this, this is no way to GTD the ordered data set.

In anticipation of you correcting this, I added a column called **RowSeq**

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a3f7f733e12f058538617ff77c9610de)**

```
Declare @OriginalTable Table ([RowSeq] int,[RecordType] varchar(50),[SequenceNumber] int,[NumberOfItems] int,[TicketHeaderKey] varchar(50),[UnitID] varchar(50))
Insert Into @OriginalTable Values 
 (1,'P',1,3,';',1)
,(2,'I',19900,0,'FA',19900)
,(3,'I',3000,0,'BK',3000)
,(4,'I',0,0,'BK',0)
,(5,'P',2,1,';',1)
,(6,'I',19900,0,'FA',19900)
,(7,'P',3,2,';',1)
,(8,'I',19900,0,'FA',19900)
,(9,'I',3000,0,'BK',3000)


Select RecordType
      ,SequenceNumber
      ,NumberOfItems
      ,TicketHeaderKey
      ,UnitID
 From  @OriginalTable
 Where RecordType='P'
 Order By [RowSeq]


Select RecordType
      ,SequenceNumber
      ,IDMasterTable 
      ,TicketHeaderKey
      ,UnitID
 From ( 
        Select *
              ,IDMasterTable = max(case when RecordType='P' then SequenceNumber end ) over (Order By RowSeq)
         From  @OriginalTable
      ) A      
 Where RecordType='I'
 Order By [RowSeq]
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the data you want to insert into each of the master and detail tables, but here is one way to do it.

For the MasterTable:

```
INSERT INTO MasterTable
SELECT 
    SequenceNumber AS id, 
    UnitId, 
    NumberOfItems, 
    TicketHeaderKey, 
    PrintType 
FROM tabletosplit 
WHERE RecordType = 'P' 
ORDER BY SequenceNumber;
```

For the detail table:

```
WITH auxtable(id, RecordType, UnitId, SequenceNumber, NumberOfItems, TicketHeaderKey, PrintType, auxnumber, parentNumberOfItems, parentid) 
AS (
SELECT 1, RecordType, UnitId, SequenceNumber, NumberOfItems, TicketHeaderKey, PrintType, 1, NumberOfItems, SequenceNumber 
FROM tabletosplit WHERE SequenceNumber = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    auxtable.id + 1,
    T.RecordType, T.UnitId, T.SequenceNumber, T.NumberOfItems, T.TicketHeaderKey, T.PrintType, 
    CASE WHEN T.RecordType = 'P' THEN 1 else auxtable.auxnumber + 1 END, 
    CASE WHEN T.RecordType = 'P' THEN T.NumberOfItems ELSE auxtable.parentNumberOfItems END, 
    CASE WHEN T.RecordType = 'P' THEN T.SequenceNumber ELSE auxtable.parentid END 
    FROM auxtable 
    INNER JOIN (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  AS id, RecordType, UnitId, SequenceNumber, NumberOfItems, TicketHeaderKey, PrintType
                FROM tabletosplit 
                WHERE SequenceNumber <> 1) AS T
    ON auxtable.id = T.id 
)
INSERT INTO DetailTable
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS id, auxtable.UnitId , auxtable.TicketHeaderKey, auxtable.PrintType, auxtable.Parentid, auxtable.auxnumber -1 as DetailIndex
FROM auxtable
WHERE auxtable.RecordType = 'I';
```

Results:

[image]

Working sample [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7e6afd44298faaef58aa3a80d898b2bb)
Hope it helps you.